# Android 14 Additional restrictions on starting activities from background

Tags: java, android

When an app sends a PendingIntent using PendingIntent#send() or similar methods, the app must now opt in if it wants to grant its own background activity launch privileges to start the pending intent. To opt in, the app should pass an ActivityOptions bundle with setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode(MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED).

This is written in Android Developers.

So i tried testing it android 14 Beta1. Target SDK: UpsideDownCake.

I first tried sending pendingIntent to another app from its background.
(without passing ActivityOptions)
But managed to send and start another app’s activity.
My question:
Is the testing order correct?
or the restriction is still not available?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); Intent.setClassName = (“another package
name”, “another class name”;

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
getApplicationContext(), 2, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
pendingIntent.send();
```

Additional info:
For the first test,
・I placed it directly into a button.
So when i press the button, pendingIntent.send() is called to launch anpther app.

result: with or without the ActivityOptions.bundle, activity could be launched.
(as explained on top)

For the second test,
・I created only one app, and placed the pendingIntent.Send() in a service class.
In the service class, i created foregroundService as well.(as you have described in the document, i used camera.)
I used adb shell am start-foreground-service -n packagame.....
to start the service..

result: with or without the ActivityOptions.bundle, activity could not be launched, but foregroundService could be launched.

※Additional note: In Android Developers, the second restrictions about starting activity by bindService(), i tested and restricition was applied,
so i assume the first restriction on pendingIntent.send() is restricted as well...but it is not going well..

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this document. Which type of are foreground service you have use

[Document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information.
Im sorry for not explaining further.

Ive added further information on my test, so i hope u could take the time to check it again.